# CSS 3 Flexbox model width jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to align and auto size box with the CSS3 flexbox model.

HTML && CSS:

```
<ul id="sect">
    <li class="">Section 1</li>
    <li class="">Section 2</li>
    <li class="">Section 3</li>
    <li class="">Section 4</li>
    <li class="">Section 5</li>
</ul>

#sect {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;    
}

#sect li {
    -webkit-flex: auto;
    flex: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 193px;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    margin-right: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

It work with flexbox model but only on Google Chrome :
[jsFiddle exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/maxence/AWS8T/)

Is it possible to reproduce this with javascript for the all navigators (FF / Safari and IE8+)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a small plugin that would do the same with jquery, it accepts one parameter - minimal width of a cell (like the one you have in css)

```
$.fn.resizeRows = function(minCellWidth) {
    return this.each(function () {
        //cache this ul
        thisul = $(this);
        //set defaul min cell width 193
        minCellWidth = minCellWidth|193;
        //total width of a row in pixels
        var totalwidth = thisul.width();
        //max count of cells that would fit per one row
        var maxcount = Math.floor(totalwidth/minCellWidth);
        //number of cells in the end that would require percentage width
        var endrows = thisul.find('li').length % maxcount;                

        $(this).find('li').each(function(index){
          if (index<maxcount||( thisul.find('li').length-index)>=maxcount) 
              $(this).width((totalwidth/maxcount)+'px');
          else      
              $(this).width(100/endrows + "%")
    })
})
}
```

You need to call it initially and bind it to widow resize event

```
$("#sect").resizeRows(193);
$(window).resize(function(){
    $("#sect").resizeRows(193);
});
```

here's modified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/vnvv3/5/)  - I commented out flex box in css, changed margin-right to 0, so that widths could be calculated properly, and set li elements to be float:left

Comment: you're welcome! it would be even better to put on window resize handler inside the plugin, so that it could be called just once